# Pre-image of conditional expectations

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ be a probability space, $S:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R^d$ a $\mathcal F$-measurable map. Let $\mathcal F_0\subseteq\mathcal F$ and $H\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ a Borel set. Let $X:=\mathbb E[1_{S\in H}\mid\mathcal F_0]$ and $F:=X^{-1}((0,1]).$ Assume that $\mathbb P(F)>0.$ Do we have $$S(\omega)\in H \text{ for all } \omega\in F $$ or $$\mathbb P(S\in H )=1?$$As an example, if $S$ is $\mathcal F_0$-measurable then we have $X=1_{S\in H}$ and the above conclusion follows deterministically. I am having problems with the fact that $X$ is defined only up to $\mathbb P$-null sets. Showing that $$\mathbb E[1_{S\in H}\mid\mathcal F_0]^{-1}((0,1])\subseteq 1_{S\in H}^{-1}((0,1])$$ would also be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe more simply, one considers $A$ in $\mathcal F$, one defines $F=[P[A\mid\mathcal F_0]\ne0]$, one assumes that $P[F]\gt0$ (note that this is equivalent to $P[A]\gt0$), and the first question is whether $F\subseteq A$.

Obvious counterexample: $A$ independent of $\mathcal F_0$ and such that $0\lt P[A]\lt1$, then $P[A\mid\mathcal F_0]=P[A]$ almost surely hence $P[F]=1$ and $F\subseteq A$ is impossible (even, only up to a null set) since $P[A]\lt1$.

The second question is whether $P[A]=1$, which is absurd hence it might be whether $P[A\mid F]=1$. The same example shows this is not so.

On the other hand, $P[A\cap F]=E[\mathbf 1_F\cdot\mathbf 1_A]=E[\mathbf 1_F\cdot P[A\mid \mathcal F_0]]$ since $F$ is $\mathcal F_0$-measurable, and the last expectation is $E[P[A\mid \mathcal F_0]]=P[A]$, thus $P[F\mid A]=1$.